# Can I walk around Easter Island alone at night?

Tags: safety, hiking, easter-island

I wanted to spend some time alone and I'd love to see the island outside Hanga Roa and without other tourists during the night.

I know wild camping is illegal (all the island is either National Park or private territory), so I'm not considering this.

Can I do some of the trails during the night? My concerns are:

- Is it legal? I didn't find anything saying that it isn't or suggesting that I'd need a guide, but better safe than sorry,
- Is is safe? I guess with small population and so many tourists it's OK, but maybe there other dangers like wild animals.

Comment: The most dangerous animals on the island are probably horses, so wildlife wise you're fine.

Comment: @BritishSam ah great, I'm fine with horses. I was more worried about stray dogs etc

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to assume this is *not* legal. Or?

Comment: @MastaBaba probably you're right, I wasn't sure if there aren't some prohibiting walking without a guide or opening hours (I'd think it's weird, but I saw it in Brazil in some national parks), seems there's no such thing though.
I'm more worried about safety, I read some complaints about wild dogs running around, not sure if it's common there.

Comment: Some of the archeological sites seem to have newish restrictions on hours and what can be accessed without a guide. I was there in January and was told some further such restrictions were coming into force later in the year. So yes, it would be best to check on the exact rules from a local. Many of the main archeological sites now have a ranger at the entrance who you could ask.

Comment: I would worry about falling off a cliff or into a hole in the night. Dark is really dark. But if it's somewhere you've been before and are aware of the hazards, that could be different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can (from personal experience) confirm that it is absolutely possible to walk around the island at night alone. However, please inform your hosts before you leave and also inform them where you plan to wander around. Just in case.

There are some closed areas which are only accessible with guides though (nature preservation and archeological sites), so make sure to be aware (again, just ask your hotel hosts) where it is ok to walk around and where it is prohibited.

I made very good experience with the folks from the Hotel Puku Vai, very friendly and knowledgeable.